# How to check content validity in Ace.js

Tags: ace-editor

I am using Ace.js for JSON and I need to check if content is valid every time I click a button. Ace.js has such validator on keyup. Therefore there should be a method to check content validity and return a Boolean.

Comment: I can see that JSON is marked as valid / invalid as I input into the text box. I'm looking for a way to see if the value passed to the onChange callback is valid or not